# Having trouble updating a local ontology with SPARQL

Tags: javascript, sparql, rdf

I have a local ontology that I want to query with SPARQL. I'm using JavaScript, so I set up a Comunica query engine and opened a SPARQL endpoint with the `comunica-sparql-file-http` util. The `SELECT` queries work as expected and return what I expect them to return. However, I'm not having much luck with the update queries, `INSERT DATA` to be specific. The endpoint returns [400] Bad request.

The request is as follows:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/sparql', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-update'
        }),
        body: query
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        params.res.send(!!response.ok);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        params.res.send(false);
    });
```

The text output of the endpoint response is as follows:

```
urn:comunica:default:rdf-update-hypermedia/mediators#main mediated over all rejecting actors:
Actor urn:comunica:default:rdf-update-hypermedia/actors#patch-sparql-update could not detect a destination with 'application/sparql-update' as 'Accept-Patch' header.
Actor urn:comunica:default:rdf-update-hypermedia/actors#put-ldp could not detect a destination with 'Allow: PUT' header.
Actor urn:comunica:default:rdf-update-hypermedia/actors#sparql could not detect a SPARQL service description or URL ending on /sparql or /update.
```

It seems as if the endpoint is in read-only mode and won't allow me to update the ontology, but I did add the `-u` when initializing the endpoint, and before that the error message did specifically say "Attempted to write in read-only mode".

I tried:

- Using the `query()` and `queryVoid()` methods of `queryEngine` instead of `fetch`; both yielded `Error: Unknown entry type: update`
- Playing around with the body of the request: tried `body: { update: query }` and `body: { query }`. Only `body: query` does not produce a parsing error.

Is there perhaps another flag that I need to use when initializing the endpoint, or some config I need to change?